# If exist can not find the file batch

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

I have a problem, I can't figure out why this is happening

I wrote a little batchfile, it opens a ftp connection, downloads a list of all ftp files in a directory and stores them in a textfile like this:

```
file.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

These are files I have downloaded trough ftp to a network share, and I want to check if they really have been downloaded into the folder, with help of this textfile.

Here is the script:

```
pushd \\server\share


doing ftp stuff, working fine, the files really do exist.
\\EDIT: Using 
mls * ftpdir.txt
to get all the files in the ftp dir.


for /F "tokens=*" %%L in (ftpdir.txt) do (

    REM another thing I tried was this:
    REM if exist %%L (
if exist %%L (
    echo %%L found
) else (
    echo not found [%%L]
    )
)
```

and a few more options. All of them went straight into the else part, saying not found.
The only thing that worked so far, was when the files where in the same folder as the script.

On a sidenote, if I do echo not found [%%L] or echo [%%L] not found it gives me a really strange output. (not only there but every similar line, containing an echo with a var and text.

On CMD (the brackets):

```
]ot found [file.xls
```

meanwhile, when I give the output to a file, it looks like this:

```
not found [file.xls ]
```

between the xls and the ] there seems to be some symbol like a newline, in editor there is a square, and when I pasted the line here, it automatically wrote the ] on a newline.

This is not so important for me that echo is not working as I would expect, but maybe it shows an error in my cmd or is in some way related.

Any help would be appreciated, why is the if exist not working?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first 3 lines are redundant. You're mapping to \\server\share which makes that the current directory. You only need the first line. At that point, as long as the files are in \\server\share, it should work. If not, you need to specify where the files live.

Comment: Okay, I removed them, it is still always entering the else part when checking if exist

Comment: take a look at your ftpdir.txt file in a hex editor and see what that extra character is. That's most likely the culprit. I'll bet if you remove them from your file, it'll work.

Comment: Well, thank you! I opened it with a hex editor and it showed me 0D 0D 0A after every file. After seeing that I opened it in notepad++ where it showed me extra lines. In the normal editor the extra 0D wasn't showing. Write this as an answer so I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description and the fact that there is a space after the filename, open the file in a hex editor and take a look. I'll bet there is an extra line feed that is causing the problem.

Comment: To add to the solution: I was using the ftp command mls and not ls to get all files in a textfile. mls somehow resulted in the extra linefeed. Using ls solved the problem completely.